# Get max date based on another column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, max

I have a table variable which consists of columns id, date and status as shown below

```
DECLARE @DateValues TABLE (
    id int identity(1,1), 
    dates datetime,
    status varchar (5)
)
```

And follows is the sample data

```
INSERT INTO @DateValues values ('5/22/2021','')
INSERT INTO @DateValues values ('5/21/2021','ABC')
INSERT INTO @DateValues values ('5/22/2021','ABC')
```

Also declared a variable as shown below.

```
DECLARE @MaxID INT
```

From this table I need to get the row which containing the maximum value of date( MAX(dates) ) where status is 'ABC', from the above sample values, I should get the 3rd row as the result and I need to assign the corresponding id value of the row id to a variable (@MaxID).

I tried following queries but getting multiple result set

```
SELECT id, MAX(dates), Footer
FROM @DateValues
WHERE STATUS = 'ABC'
GROUP BY id, STATUS

SELECT id, dates, status
FROM @DateValues
WHERE dates = (
    SELECT MAX(dates)
    FROM @DateValues
);
```

I need something like:

```
@MaxID = id
FROM @DateValues
WHERE dates = (
    SELECT MAX(dates)
    FROM @DateValues
    WHERE STATUS='ABC'
);
```

Please help.

Comment: What is the required result ?

Comment: need to assign @MaxID with id of maximum date where status='ABC'

Comment: Please actually show your desired result(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
           SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dates DESC)
           FROM   @DateValues
           WHERE  status = 'ABC'           
       ) AS D
WHERE  D.RN = 1
```